# Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_variables' has the wrong structure

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'v updated mysql on ec2 Linux server from 5.5 to 5.7.20 (and having 5.7.21 on my ubuntu).

since the upgrade, I'm not able to connect to the mysql server through the mysql workbench.
but the website works with no issues.

getting this:
Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_variables' has the wrong structure
is there any log file for these workbench connection test?

Comment: forget it. just restarted mysql locally and on the server as well. IT IS WORKING NOW!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forget it. just restarted mysql locally and on the server as well. 
IT IS WORKING NOW!

Comment: I can confirm having the same issue after upgrading mysql, and restarting somehow fixed it.